# use phtml code instead of xml code to display reviews

Tags: magento

i added below code in catalog.xml file , now reviews section is displaying in product view page. but i want to display that only under particular tab.

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/></block>
```

Is there any way we can use phtml code to display this review section.

so i am planning to use that phtml code under that tab

Comment: In which tab you want to show it ? Do you have all the tab code showing on view.phtml ?

Comment: @PankajPareek please check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) , under `Review` tab i want to display the review section

Comment: @PankajPareek i am displaying 4 tabs in view page, under one particular tab , i want to display review section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$reviewListBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/product_view_list');
$reviewFormBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/form');

echo $reviewListBlock->setTemplate('review/product/view/list.phtml')->toHtml();
echo $reviewFormBlock->setTemplate('review/form.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call in particular tab content `getChildHtml` function to call particular block content. like below:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review');

echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form');
```

Comment: i dont know why it didt worked for me. may be i did something wrong. Thansk a lot for your support. i got solution.

Comment: if you click on `Add review` tab [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) , you can see 2 parts , one is reviews that is already posted.
another section is `write your own review` i want to display `write your own review` section in another tab.

Comment: i got solution for that one also, i have one more problem i will post new question and inform you soon.